# php calculated CRC-CCITT (XModem)

Tags: php, crc, xmodem

I'm trying to implement a CRC-CCITT (XModem) check in php without success. Does anyone know how to do it? I expected crc16('test') will return `0x9B06`.

Comment: This one looks straight forward http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834541/crc-4-implementation-in-c-sharp it's C# but looks like it should be simple to adopt for PHP

Comment: It's not implementation XModex algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple bit-wise calculation of the XMODEM 16-bit CRC, in C:

```
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned crc16xmodem_bit(unsigned crc, void const *data, size_t len) {
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= (unsigned)(*(unsigned char const *)data++) << 8;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 0x8000 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021 : crc << 1;
    }
    crc &= 0xffff;
    return crc;
}
```

This was generated by my [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) software, which also generates byte-wise and word-wise versions for speed.

This can be easily converted to php.