# CRC 4 implementation for C#

Tags: c#, .net, checksum, crc

Solved by this code -> https://gist.github.com/Sbreitzke/b26107798eee74e39ff85800abf71fb1

---

I searched the web for a CRC 4 implementation in C# because I have to calculate a checksum  by

> Changing the numbers of the barcode into Hex representation, then to bytes and then to bits and then calculate a CRC4 checksum on the bit stream.

I already found this question from 8 years ago without an answer
[CRC-4 implementation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834541/crc-4-implementation-in-c-sharp).

I tried changing the CRC 8 and 16 implementations to CRC 4 but they don't quite get the result I require.

`0130E0928270FFFFFFF` should evaluate to `7`.

I found two C implementation but was unable to convert them to C#. For example this one:

```
 short[] crc4_tab = {
 0x0, 0x7, 0xe, 0x9, 0xb, 0xc, 0x5, 0x2,
 0x1, 0x6, 0xf, 0x8, 0xa, 0xd, 0x4, 0x3,
};

/**
* crc4 - calculate the 4-bit crc of a value.
* @crc:  starting crc4
* @x:    value to checksum
* @bits: number of bits in @x to checksum
*
* Returns the crc4 value of @x, using polynomial 0b10111.
*
* The @x value is treated as left-aligned, and bits above @bits are ignored
* in the crc calculations.
*/
short crc4(uint8_t c, uint64_t x, int bits)
{
    int i;

    /* mask off anything above the top bit */
    x &= (1ull << bits) -1;

    /* Align to 4-bits */
    bits = (bits + 3) & ~0x3;

    /* Calculate crc4 over four-bit nibbles, starting at the MSbit */
    for (i = bits - 4; i >= 0; i -= 4)
    c = crc4_tab[c ^ ((x >> i) & 0xf)];

    return c;
}
```

My current generation code (unit test) looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void x()
{
    var ordnungskennzeichen = 01;
    var kundennummer = 51251496;
    var einlieferungsbel = 9999;
    var sendungsnr = 16777215;

    var hex_ordnungskennzeichen = ordnungskennzeichen.ToString("x2");
    var hex_kundennummer = kundennummer.ToString("x2");
    var hex_einlieferungsbel = einlieferungsbel.ToString("x2");
    var hex_sendungsnr = sendungsnr.ToString("x2");

    var complete = hex_ordnungskennzeichen + hex_kundennummer + hex_einlieferungsbel + hex_sendungsnr;

    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(complete);

    //var computeChecksum = crc4(???);
    //   Console.WriteLine(computeChecksum);

}

short[] crc4_tab = {
    0x0, 0x7, 0xe, 0x9, 0xb, 0xc, 0x5, 0x2,
    0x1, 0x6, 0xf, 0x8, 0xa, 0xd, 0x4, 0x3,
};

/**
* crc4 - calculate the 4-bit crc of a value.
* @crc:  starting crc4
* @x:    value to checksum
* @bits: number of bits in @x to checksum
*
* Returns the crc4 value of @x, using polynomial 0b10111.
*
* The @x value is treated as left-aligned, and bits above @bits are ignored
* in the crc calculations.
*/

short crc4(byte c, ulong x, int bits)
{
    int i;

    /* mask off anything above the top bit */
    x &= ((ulong)1 << bits) -1;

    /* Align to 4-bits */
    bits = (bits + 3) & ~0x3;

    /* Calculate crc4 over four-bit nibbles, starting at the MSbit */
    for (i = bits - 4; i >= 0; i -= 4)
        c = (byte) crc4_tab[c ^ ((x >> i) & 0xf)];

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Really did you tried to convert the code? That code works exactly as-is with three minor changes...

Comment: in this case I was not sure how to convert ` x &= (1ull << bits) -1;` to c# and how to pass my argument (currently a byte array) into it.
I changed the signature to `short crc4(short c, long x, int bits)` - is this correct?

Comment: No, `1ull` is `(ulong)1` in c#, `uint8_t` is `byte` and `uint64_t` is `ulong`

Comment: I am sorry I don't get it. If I change the types as you say the short coming out of `crc4_tag` is not aligning with `byte c`. I can cast it to make the compiler happy but I don't have any clue how to call the method then. The `c` parameter can be used as an initializer? so I can pass 0? why is it a parameter at all not a variable? Is `x` the digit I want to hash? it is too long for a long. `bits` makes no sense to me as long as I don`t understand `x`.

Comment: So how do you know 0130E0928270FFFFFFF should evaluate to 7 (by the way it's not even number of bytes there - is that number correct)?

Comment: You must cast `crc_tab` to `byte`: `c = (byte)crc4_tab[c ^ ((x >> i) & 0xf)];`

Comment: @Evk: The document with the requirement came from the german post (Deutsche Post) and contains an example.

I did the cast as described but how do I call it? The only input parameter I have is a byte[] or a string containing "0130e0928270fffffff".
I added the first part of the code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further testing and communication with the Deutsche Post AG we made a correct implementation (for the purpose of Deutsche Post at least):

https://gist.github.com/Sbreitzke/b26107798eee74e39ff85800abf71fb1

Answer (score 3):

Converting it to C# is not very hard. `c` is initial or previous nibble (4-bit number), `x` is 64bit number you want to calculate crc4 of, `bits` is number of bits in that 64bit number to actually use (the rest are ignored). Since you have array of bytes - you don't need to use 64bit number as `x` - use can just use byte. Then the first two lines are irrelevant for you, because all they do is throwing away irrelevant bits from 64bit number and ensuring `bits` is divisable by 4. So after removing irrelevant lines your implementation becomes:

```
static readonly byte[] crc4_tab = {
    0x0, 0x7, 0xe, 0x9, 0xb, 0xc, 0x5, 0x2,
    0x1, 0x6, 0xf, 0x8, 0xa, 0xd, 0x4, 0x3,
};

static byte crc4(byte c, byte x) {
    var low4Bits = x & 0x0F;
    var high4Bits = x >> 4;
    c = crc4_tab[c ^ high4Bits];
    c = crc4_tab[c ^ low4Bits];

    return c;
}

static byte crc4(byte[] array) {
    byte start = 0;
    foreach (var item in array) {
        start = crc4(start, item);
    }
    return start;
}
```

Comment: woho the result is 7. Thank you very much, also for the explanation! :)

Comment: @Zebi I'd suggest to test this on more strings, because you took some random code from internet, then some another random guy converted it to C# (and maybe even incorrectly), so who knows what can go wrong here :)

Comment: Of course I will check it further, the problem is that we have only one example but they will make a further approval so we will see ;) They send two examples and in one of them they even got the conversion to hex wrong so this can get interesting. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zebi I dont get it... `crc4(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("0130E0928270FFFFFFF")` will return `E` and not `7`?!

Comment: @david after further testing we modified it and this should work correctly: https://gist.github.com/Sbreitzke/b26107798eee74e39ff85800abf71fb1

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of Deutsche Post as well, I'd like to contribute a rather less complex algorithm wich may more easily be translated into other languages as well:

```
       private string crc4(string sText) {
        int iCRC;
        int iPoly;
        int iByte;
        int iBit;
        byte[] bText;
        sText = sText.Replace(" ", "");
        iPoly = 0x13 << 3;
        iCRC = 0;
        bText = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sText);
        for (iByte=0; iByte < bText.Length; iByte++){
            iCRC = iCRC ^ bText[iByte];
            for (iBit = 0; iBit < 8; iBit++){
                if ((iCRC & 0x80) != 0){
                    iCRC = iCRC ^ iPoly;
                }
                iCRC = iCRC << 1;
            }
        }
        iCRC = iCRC >> 4;

        return String.Format("{0:X}", iCRC);
    }
```

Fed with  i.e. "A0 0101 002B 00 000C D10" the above code will calculate "F" as the correct check digit. (and tested with numerous other input values)